# How can I get Python jsonpickle to work recursively?

Tags: python, json, jsonpickle

I'm having trouble getting Python's jsonpickle 0.4.0 to "recurse" in to custom objects that contain custom objects.  Here's sample code that shows my problem.

```
import jsonpickle
import jsonpickle.handlers

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.contents = args

class BallHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):    
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        data['color'] = obj.color
        return data

class BoxHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):    
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        data['contents'] = obj.contents
        return data

jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(Ball, BallHandler)
jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(Box, BoxHandler)

# works OK -- correctly prints: {"color": "white"}
white_ball = Ball('white')
print jsonpickle.encode(white_ball, unpicklable=False)

# works OK -- correctly prints: [{"color": "white"}, {"color": "green"}]
green_ball = Ball('green')
balls = [white_ball, green_ball]
print jsonpickle.encode(balls, unpicklable=False)

# works OK -- correctly prints: {"contents": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
box_1 = Box(1, 2, 3, 4)
print jsonpickle.encode(box_1, unpicklable=False)

# dies with "Ball object is not JSON serializable"
box_2 = Box(white_ball, green_ball)
print jsonpickle.encode(box_2, unpicklable=False)
```

Balls have "color", Boxes have "contents".  If I have a [native] array of Balls, then `jsonpickle` works.  If I have a Box of [native] ints, then `jsonpickle` works.

But if I have a Box of Balls, `jsonpickle` bombs with `"Ball object is not JSON serializable"`.

From the stacktrace, I have the hunch that the encoder is leaving `jsonpickle` and going off to some other JSON library... that apparently doesn't know that I've registered the BallHandler.

How can I fix this up?

By the way, my sample is NOT expressly using any part of Django, but I will be needing this to work in a Django app.

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY INPUT!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can call back to the pickling context to continue the pickling.

```
class BoxHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):
def flatten(self, obj, data):
    return [self.context.flatten(x,reset=False) for x in obj.contents]
```

This seems to be similar to how the built in _list_recurse() function handles this case in pickler.py:44, as flatten() just calls self._flatten (after optionally resetting the state variables).

`def _list_recurse(self, obj):
        return [self._flatten(v) for v in obj]`

I'm just testing on this now, and the _depth seems to be maintained as expected.

Comment: THIS was the answer I was looking for.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

First, why are you creating custom handlers in the first place? You're attempting to do exactly the same thing the default handlers already do. Remove those two `register` lines and call `encode` with and without `unpicklable=False` with all of those objects, and you will get the same results—except that it will work exactly the way you want with boxes full of balls, instead of failing.

If you look through the tutorial, API, test cases, and samples, they never create a custom handler to simulate a collection like this. (For example, take a look at the `Node`/`Document`/`Section` classes in the test suites ([`samples.py`](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle/blob/master/tests/samples.py) and [`document_test.py`](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle/blob/master/tests/document_test.py)).) So, I think you're trying to do something that you weren't expected to do, and isn't intended to be doable.

But, let's look at your actual question: Why doesn't it work?

Well, that one's easy. You're doing it wrong. According to the documentation for [`BaseHandler.flatten`](http://jsonpickle.github.com/api.html#jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler.flatten), you're supposed to:

> Flatten obj into a json-friendly form.

So, given this:

```
class BoxHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):    
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        data['contents'] = obj.contents
        return data
```

You're effectively promising that `obj.contents` is in JSON-friendly form. But it's not; it's a `list` of `Ball` objects.

So, what's the right answer? Well, you *could* flatten each element in contents the same way you're being flattened. You'd think there must be some easy way to do that, but honestly, I don't see anything in the API, docs, samples, or unit tests, so I guess there isn't, so you'll have to do it manually. Presumably something like this (untested):

```
class BoxHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):    
    def flatten(self, obj, data):
        p = jsonpickle.Pickler()
        data['contents'] = [p.flatten(elem) for elem in obj.contents]
        return data
```

But… since you're not getting the same `Pickler` that's being used to pickle you—and I don't see any way that you can—this is likely going to violate the `maxdepth` and `unpicklable` parameters of `encode`.

So, maybe there *is* no right way to do this.

Comment: Right.  All the elements of `data['contents']` ARE JSON-friendly... because I've registered a handler, and JSON therefore knows how to encode them!

Comment: No, that doesn't make then JSON-friendly. JSON doesn't know how to encode them; `jsonpickle` does. That's not the same thing. Even if the wording is a bit ambiguous, the stack trace makes it obvious that it wants actual JSON-friendly, not just further-flattenable-friendly. (And if you think about it, this makes sense. If you wanted to implement some kind of collection that worked differently from the usual `list`/`set`/`dict` types—say, a binary tree—you obviously need to flatten it all the way or it has no idea what you're actually giving it.)

Comment: As for "why am I creating custom handlers in the first place": umm... this is SAMPLE code.  Demonstrating the problem.  It's not my real code.  The "real" objects I want to encode are complicated Django models.  But I only need to encode the portion of the objects that I need to send out to my web application.  So I need control of the JSON-encode.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug to me and a principle one at that. If `jsonpickle` is about adding custom objects handling to `json`, it should integrate into the latter rather than attempting to "preprocess" the content for it. The present state of demanding users to handle this themselves in whatever way [as abarnert said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329531/how-can-i-get-python-jsonpickle-to-work-recursively#answer-14329603) is laying blame on another's door IMO.

If I were you, I'd go for fixing this myself or make my objects JSON-friendly as they are - e.g. making them look like native Python data structures (which JSON is an alternative representation of). An easier way is to avoid such constructs which is a kludge, of course.

Comment: I don't mind the "pre-process" step.  But I think that the framework is not DOING the recursion is odd.  I mean, after all: 1) doing the JSON-encode of the contained objects wold be wrong (since it would result in double-encoding).  2) and I don't have to "pre-process" my contained items like integers.  I guess I could work-around with PRE-FLATTENING my "contained things".... but that just seems odd to me.  After all, someone AFTER the Box.flatten() is still JSON-encoding the integers!  Why can't it do my Balls, too?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Doing the recursion is essentially redoing the majority of the work of `json` for a second time - that's probably why they didn't implement this.

Comment: If you read over the docs (and my edited answer) and look through the samples and tests, I'm pretty sure the OP has misinterpreted what jsonpickle is and how it's supposed to be used, and is therefore trying to do the wrong thing. The only bug is that it's harder than it should be to implement handlers that do the exact same thing as the defaults—but, since the defaults already work exactly the same as the defaults, it's not that huge of a bug.