# JSON Pickle serialize object list

Tags: python, json, serialization, jsonpickle

I want to serialize a list of objects using `jsonpickle`. Each of these objects contains a list of objects within them:

```py
class ImageManipulationConfiguration:
    region_list = []
    
    def to_json(self):
        return jsonpickle.encode(self.region_list, indent=4,
                                 separators=(',', ': '))
```

here, `region_list` contains objects of this class:

```py
class ImageManipulationRegion:
    image_manipulation_element_list = []
```

Inside `image_manipulation_element_list`, there are objects of class inheriting this class:

```py
class ImageManipulationElement
```

When I call my `to_json` function, only the top level items in the `region_list` are serialized, the sub object within the `image_manipulation_element_list` lists are not included. Is there a way to recursively include everything using `jsonpickle`?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [How can I get Python `jsonpickle` to work recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14329531/21350362)

Comment: Look at my answer friend.

Answer (score 1):

Answer :-

1. Use `max_depth=4`
2. And change separaters
   Lile below.

```
def to_json(self):
    return jsonpickle.encode(self.region_list, indent=4,
                                 separators=(', ', ': '),max_depth=4)
```

Or
use this below code.

```
class BoxHandler(jsonpickle.handlers.BaseHandler):
def flatten(self, obj, data):
    return [self.context.flatten(x,reset=False) for x in obj.contents]
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44665982/13861187)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the jsonpickle.set_encoder_options function to set the indent and separators parameters for all future encodes.

```
import jsonpickle
from jsonpickle.picklers.base import Pickler
from jsonpickle.util import encode

class ImageManipulationConfiguration:
region_list = []

 def to_json(self):
    return encode(self.region_list, Pickler, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

class ImageManipulationRegion:
image_manipulation_element_list = []

class ImageManipulationElement:
pass

jsonpickle.set_encoder_options('json', indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

immc = ImageManipulationConfiguration()
immc.region_list.append(ImageManipulationRegion())
immc.region_list[0]. 
image_manipulation_element_list.append(ImageManipulationElement( 
   ))

 print(immc.to_json())
```

This will output:

```
[
{
    "image_manipulation_element_list": [
        {
            "__setstate__": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The sub-objects within image_manipulation_element_list are now included in the encoded JSON.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the `unpicklable` parameter in jsonpickle to recursively include all objects. Set the `unpicklable` parameter to `True` when calling `jsonpickle.encode` to include all objects, even those that are not directly referenced by the top-level object.

hre's how you can modify your `to_json` method:

```py
import jsonpickle

class ImageManipulationConfiguration:
    region_list = []

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonpickle.encode(self.region_list, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), unpicklable=True)
```

this should include all objects within `region_list`, including the sub-objects within `image_manipulation_element_list`.

Comment: This parameter is True by default, manually setting it to true changes nothing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can achieve recursive serialization of objects using jsonpickle by customizing the serialization process for each of your classes. To do this, you'll need to define a custom handler for each class that specifies how to serialize its instances and their nested objects.

Here's how you can achieve this for your classes:

Define custom handlers for each class:

```
import jsonpickle

class ImageManipulationConfiguration:
    region_list = []

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonpickle.encode(self.region_list, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

class ImageManipulationRegion:
    image_manipulation_element_list = []

class ImageManipulationElement:
    pass

def encode_ImageManipulationConfiguration(obj):
    return {
        'region_list': obj.region_list
    }

def encode_ImageManipulationRegion(obj):
    return {
        'image_manipulation_element_list': obj.image_manipulation_element_list
    }

def encode_ImageManipulationElement(obj):
    # Define how to serialize ImageManipulationElement objects if needed
    pass

# Register custom handlers
jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(ImageManipulationConfiguration, encode_ImageManipulationConfiguration)
jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(ImageManipulationRegion, encode_ImageManipulationRegion)
jsonpickle.handlers.registry.register(ImageManipulationElement, encode_ImageManipulationElement)
```

Now, when you call to_json on an instance of ImageManipulationConfiguration, it will include the custom serialization logic for each class:

```
config = ImageManipulationConfiguration()
# Populate config.region_list with instances of ImageManipulationRegion and nested ImageManipulationElement objects

json_string = config.to_json()
print(json_string)
```

By providing custom serialization logic for each class, you can make sure that nested objects are properly serialized when you call to_json. This allows you to achieve recursive serialization with jsonpickle.